# Make a custom form validition algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am using this validator: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.js

I placed this on line 1056:

```
adresnumber: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9][0-9?][0-9?][a-zA-Z?][a-zA-Z?]$/.test(value);
},
```

Now I have to add this as adres number 123AB or something with three numbers and two letters, how can I make it allow [0-9], [0-9][a-zA-Z], [0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z], etc.. to max three numbers and two letters, the letters always need to be after the number. How can I achieve this

Comment: Applying regexes to addresses is a HORRIBLE idea. Not all addresses follow the same schema!

Comment: @ThiefMaster and what do I have to do when I still want that?

Comment: Tell your boss it's a stupid idea? ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Oke, I will do that :)

Comment: Can You share all input posibilities to validate?